# How do I test my flash message when I'm using the vcr gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

I am new to VCR [vcr gem](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) and testing it in a rails application. The problem that I am facing is that I am unable to my flash messages and redirects using VCR and I am not sure how to get around it. Here is my controller action I am trying to create.

```
  def create
    @response = HTTParty.post('https://reseller.cdnify.com/api/v1/resources',
      {basic_auth: { username: cdn_params[:api_key], password: 'x'}, body: { alias: cdn_params[:resource_name], origin: cdn_params[:resource_origin]}})

    if @response.parsed_response['resources']
      flash[:notice] = 'Successfully Created Resource.'
    else
      @response.parsed_response['errors'].each do |error|
        flash[:error] = "#{error['code']}" + ': ' + "#{error['message']}"
      end
    end

    redirect_to cdns_path(ssl_slug: @ssl_slug)
  end
```

I have these following tests in my `controller_test.rb` file:

```
  describe 'create' do

    let(:cdn_resource) do
      HTTParty.post('https://reseller.cdnify.com/api/v1/resources', {
        basic_auth: { username: 'api_key', password: 'x'},
        body: { alias: 'somewebsite', origin: 'http://www.somewebsite.com' }
      })
    end

    it "returns a succesful response for cdnify request" do
      VCR.use_cassette('cdnify_valid_result_for_cdn') do
        response = HTTParty.post('https://reseller.cdnify.com/api/v1/resources', {
          basic_auth: { username: 'api_key', password: 'x'},
          body: { alias: 'mywebsite', origin: 'http://www.mywebsite.com' }
        })

        assert_not_nil response.parsed_response['resources']
        assert_nil response.parsed_response['errors']
      end
    end

    it 'returns an error with an invalid cdnify request' do
      VCR.use_cassette('cdnify_invalid_result_for_cdn') do
        response = cdn_resource

        assert_not_nil response.parsed_response['errors']
        assert_nil response.parsed_response['resources']
      end
    end
  end
```

Basically, I am testing a good and bad response. These tests pass but the problem that I am getting is that I can't test my redirects nor my flash messages. I've tried placing them in the `VCR` do block and outside of the block but I am not able to get my tests pass. They seem to be missing. What am I doing wrong? Furthermore, my `simplecov` coverage is saying that I am not executing any of the code in the `create` method. Why is this the case?

## EDIT

As mentioned by mrzasa, I separated the service into a services folder but now I'm just missing one small crucial step in the testing process. Am I to mock the http response with mocha or can I just simply use the cassette generated to do so?

```
  describe 'create' do
    it 'correctly creates a cdn resource, redirects to cdns#index, and shows successful flash message' do
      post :create, params: {api_key: 'random_api_key_12345678',
                              resource_name: 'somewebsite',
                                resource_origin: 'http://www.somewebsite.com' }

      ############ mocking here? #############
      Do I use mocha to construct the actual response hash?
      ####################################################

      assert flash[:notice]
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a direct answer to this question, but may help in general. I'd discourage you from calling external services directly from the controller. It's messy. It's hard to test. It's impossible to reuse.

Wrap the cdnify integration in a separate class. You'll be able to test this class with VCR. In the controller spec, you'll mock it and test the flash easily.

Comment: Ok, I think I like this approach. Thanks for the input.

Comment: If it helps, please consider upvoting, it's worth even more than accepting

Comment: Hey @mrzasa, A quick follow up. I separated the service into its own folder just like you recommended in your answer. If you have a moment to spare, could you look at my edit? I'm a little confused about the mocking of the controller because I was wondering if you were referring to something like `mocha` or somehow using the vcr cassette in it.

Comment: Please, ask a separate question, it'll be easier to help you there

Comment: Here is the question I made. @mrzasa https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58862193/what-is-the-proper-way-of-mocking-my-controller-create-action-that-includes-an. If you do have a free moment to look at it, I'd appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> simplecov coverage is saying that I am not executing any of the code in the create method. Why is this the case?

Your tests aren't hitting your controller. You need to add a line with something like `post :create, params: {}`.